# "The weather was getting worse and getting to the camp was a (require)"

Tags: sentence-construction, exam-questions

There is a task. Write down the appropriate root word for the word inside the parentheses.

> The weather was getting worse and getting to the camp was a (require)

So would it be correct if I replace the word require with "requirement"?

Comment: Yes, syntactically you're quite correct that "requirement" is the noun form derived from the verb "to require". But idiomatically / stylistically the example isn't so good.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Reinstate Monica, thanks a lot!

Comment: It might help to consider using an ***adjective*** rather than a noun in your context. The "past participle used adjectivally" *(...was **required**)* is syntactically valid - as is *...was **requisite*** (another derived adjectival form), but they're not at all idiomatic for your context. Suitable adjectives might include *getting to the camp was **vital / crucial / critical / urgent / imperative / necessary / ...***

Comment: I agree with you. But this sentence is borrowed from the  Reader's Digest magazine.

Comment: I don't understand. Does *Reader's Digest* go in for this kind of "teaching English to non-native speakers" nowadays? I doubt if I've seen a copy myself for at least 30 years, but I'm sure they never used to do that.

Comment: Well, actually, it's not the Reader's Digest  who goes in for teaching  English to non-native speakers. This sentence, that was in the English language test,  was borrowed from that magazine. The test itself is compiled, as far as I could understand,  by the non-native English language teacher.

Comment: Well all I can say is it's a poor quality "test". Perhaps the *original* Readers Digest version had the (somewhat more natural, imho) version *...was a **necessity***, but the test-setter couldn't think what "verb" should go in brackets for that one, so he just switched it to something where he *did* know the base verb form. Anyway, I'm sure you've got the answer to your homework problem.

Comment: Thank you very much for an exhaustive answer.